# Yii2 - REST + CRUD - best practices implementation

Tags: rest, crud, yii2

As far as I understood, unlike Rails, Yii2 still doesn't use RESTful routing for CRUDs.

What could be the most efficient way to generate new CRUD with **gii** and add REST routing support to it?

I've done some background search and found the following:

- a lot of information about how to easily build REST API application - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html (which is not a thing I really need - it's only useful for backend applications)
- an article by **qiangxue** https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/rest-routing.md on how to enable REST routing for CRUDs
- a gist added by **cebe** (https://gist.github.com/cebe/5674918) doing almost the same thing like **qiangxue** proposed in other way

So it's all about configuring UrlManager and implemetation of backend API applications.

Unfortunately, I also need to *somehow* add a REST routing support to CRUD controller generated by default (with its verb-based filters and a base class that is not specialized for REST, unlike **yii\rest\ActiveController** for example). At the same time a generated by default GridView widget code doesn't support REST routes, but only utilizes GET+POST verbs.

Really appreciate certain list of things to do :)

Comment: what's the problem?